# Efficiently apply different functions based on observation type in R

Tags: r, performance

Suppose that I have a data set `A` with at least a `"Type"` column and a `"Data"` column containing T different observation types, for each I would apply a different function:

```
funlist <- c(fun1, fun2,..., funT)
```

I can accomplish this the following ways:

Method 1: `sapply`

```
for(t in 1:T){
    sapply(A[A[,"Type"]==t,"Data"],funlist[[t]])
}
```

Method 2: `mapply`

```
funvector <- rep(NaN,length(A[,"Type"]))
for(t in 1:T){
    funvector[A[,"Type"]]==t] <- funlist[[t]]
}
mapply(function(fun, x) fun(x), funvector, A[,"Data"])
```

Method 2 is especially undesirable since it creates one additional object, but in either approach I cannot avoid creating `for` loops. Since I'm working with data sets so large that memory constraint is a concern, are there more efficient ways of coding this problem such that memory usage is minimized, even if at a reasonable cost of speed?

Comment: there's a syntax error in there; `function(fun x)`  is not R.  Do you mean `function(fun,x)`.  I assume it is, so I changed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of other options:

## Base R

```
A <- data.frame(Type=c(1,1,2,2), Data=c(0.5,1,100,101))
funlist <- list(exp, log)

by(A, A$Type, FUN=function(DF) funlist[[DF$Type[1]]](DF$Data) ) 
#A$Type: 1
#[1] 1.648721 2.718282
#----------------------------------------- 
#A$Type: 2
#[1] 4.605170 4.615121
```

## dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(Data=funlist[[Type[1]]](Data))

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: Type

#  Type     Data
#1    1 1.648721
#2    1 2.718282
#3    2 4.605170
#4    2 4.615121
```

## data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
A[, .(Data=funlist[[unlist(.BY)]](Data)), by=Type]

#   Type     Data
#1:    1 1.648721
#2:    1 2.718282
#3:    2 4.605170
#4:    2 4.615121
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select the function to apply at the time you need to apply it:

```
mapply(function(d,t) funlist[[t]](d), A$Data, A$Type)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the first method to use `split` and `lapply` which would avoid the for loop as well as selecting indexes for each unique "Type".

```
lapply(split(A, A[,"Type"]), function(Atype) 
       sapply(Atype[,"Data"],funlist[[Atype[1,"Type"]]]))
```